# JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(x)) Purpose?

Tags: javascript, json

While I was working on a project, I came across this snippet of code:

```
var params = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(defaultParams));
```

Does this code actually do anything?

Comment: It can create a [simple clone of the object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-clone-an-object). Note the [2nd answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5344074) by Corban Brook.

Comment: It also validates that the object is serializable (it contains only  primitives & no cycles).

Answer (score 33, accepted):

It's a way of cloning an object, so that you get a complete copy that is unique but has the same properties as the cloned object.

```
var defaultParams = { a : 'b' };
var params = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(defaultParams));

console.log( params.a ); // b
console.log( defaultParams.a ); // b
console.log( params === defaultParams ); // false
```

The above outputs `false` because even though both objects have the `a` property, with the value `b`, there are different objects that are independent of each other (they don't refer to the same reference).

The JSON method will only work with basic properties - no functions or methods.

Comment: After years of using this "trick", I just realized - it messes up the date!! I got date property in output object in ISO format, as if I was invoking toISOString() method on it!

Comment: More cons of using this method of cloning given here: https://medium.com/@pmzubar/why-json-parse-json-stringify-is-a-bad-practice-to-clone-an-object-in-javascript-b28ac5e36521 It also messes up on NAN and Infinity.

Answer (score 1):

You can break the connection between two arrays.

For example:

```
const bulkAssignTreeView = JSON.stringify(this.bulkAssignTreeViewData);
this.bulkAssignTreeViewData = JSON.parse(bulkAssignTreeView);
```